# Where do android-library .classfiles live?

Tags: android

I'm using eclipse, and I'm trying to figure out how android library projects work. I'm using actionbarsherlock as an android library example.

In my main project's /bin folder, I see the following:

```
/bin
  |- com
      |- actionbarsherlock
      |    |- R.class
      |    |- R$array.class
      |- me
          |- myproject
               |- ActivityMain.class
               |- App.class
               |- R.class
               |- R$array.class
               ...
```

So what's confusing is that there are some R.class files in the /actionbarsherlock folder (within my main project's /bin folder as above). But the rest of the actionbarsherlock .class files are not present there (though they do exist in the actionbarsherlock project's /bin folder, stuff like ActionBarSherlock.class).

Why are only these few .class files pulled into my project's /bin folder, and not the others? Does eclipse import them at export time to stick them into the apk?

Thanks

Comment: Yeah. Eclipse is strange to understand ( in my view). Clean your project. Look at the structure. Build the project. Look at the structure. That I think should help.

Comment: I think your ActionBarSherlock files may get pasted in the .APK if they are linked as an external resource or library. As Connor T said Eclipse is hard to understand sometimes, so I won't pretend that this is a comprehensive answer.